# Upgrading to Assets 2 broke images and file uploads

Tags: assets, pixelandtonic

**Problem**
After upgrading from Assets 1.0.something to 2.0.3, thumbnails stopped showing up and uploading broke. After doing some digging, I found some PHP errors hidden in the request log:

Excerpt:

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  fopen(/system/expressionengine/cache/assets/tmp_storage/assets_tmp_510bba325d6994.05248213): failed to open stream: No such file or directory</p>
<p>Filename: assets/helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 448</p>
```

Assets is using the cache folder in the CP folder ref. line 573-577:

```
$cache_path = self::_get_EE()->config->item('cache_path');
if (empty($cache_path))
{
    $cache_path = APPPATH.'cache/';
}
```

The webserver doesn't have write permission there. I've tried overriding the cache_path of EE, but it doesn't seem to fix it.

Could anyone shed some lights on how to override the cache path for Assets? Do anyone know if there is a list of Assets config overrides somewhere?

**Details**
ExpressionEngine v. 2.0.5
Assets 2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Fred,

You will need to set system/expressionengine/cache to 777 permissions - or be on a setup where it is writable by your user and group without 777 permissions (such as how EngineHosting sets things up).

That should fix the writing to your cache file pretty easily.  Are you having trouble writing any other caches? The easiest way to find out is to turn some template caching on and check those folders for files.

-Lisa